# FMDB: put the data in advance

Tags: ios, xcode, sqlite, fmdb

I manage SQLite data by FMDB.

In this App, I'd like to put the data in advance, so I made the dbfile `sample.db` in advance by `terminal` and `Lita`, copied it and imported into the project.
Problem is that you cannot update the db.
Even though called `saveData`, Column `title` is Empty.
How do I need to fix to update the db?

・In `sample.db`, there is a table `events`.
・The table `events` schema is `(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, day TEXT, title TEXT, time INTEGER);`
・You add the data `Event` to the table `events`.

Now, you call the method `saveData` and put `"test"` into `events`.

Event.h

```
@interface Event : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, assign) NSInteger eventId;
@property (nonatomic,   copy) NSString* day;
@property (nonatomic,   copy) NSString* title;
@property (nonatomic, assign) NSInteger time;
```

DetailViewController.m

```
- (void)saveData:(id)sender
{
    Event* newEvent = [[Event alloc]init];
    newEvent.title = @“test";

    [self.delegate editEventDidFinish:self.event newEvent:newEvent];

@end
```

MasterViewController.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
     [super viewDidLoad];   
     self.daoEvents = [[DaoEvents alloc] init];
}

- (void)editEventDidFinish:(Event *)oldEvent newEvent:(Event *)newEvent
{
     [self.daoEvents update:newEvent];               
     [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}

- (void)removeOldEnent:(Event*)oldEvent
{
     [self.daoEvents remove:oldEvent.eventId];
}
```

DaoEvents.m

```
    #define DB_FILE_NAME @“sample.db"
    #define SQL_UPDATE @"UPDATE events SET day = ?, title = ?, time = ? WHERE id = ?;”
    #define SQL_DELETE @"DELETE FROM events WHERE id = ?;"

    - (FMDatabase *)dbConnect
    {
        NSArray  *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains( NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES );
        NSString* dir = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

        return [FMDatabase databaseWithPath:[dir stringByAppendingPathComponent:DB_FILE_NAME]];
    }

    - (BOOL)update:(Event *)event
    {
        FMDatabase* db = [self dbConnect];
        [db open];

        BOOL success = [db executeUpdate:SQL_UPDATE, event.day, event.title, [NSNumber numberWithInt:event.time],[NSNumber numberWithInteger:event.eventId]]; 

        [db close];

        NSLog(@"%@", event.title);  //correctly outputs “test"

        return success;
    }

    - (BOOL)remove:(NSInteger)eventId
    {
        FMDatabase* db = [self dbConnect];
        [db open];

        BOOL isSucceeded = [db executeUpdate:SQL_DELETE, [NSNumber numberWithInteger:eventId]];

        [db close];

        return isSucceeded;
    }
```

How do I need to fix to update the db?
Thank you.

Comment: You are deleting a record right before you attempt to do the update. Is the deleted record the one with the `id` that you're trying to update? If so, remove the `DELETE` if you really meant to update it. If you intended to delete and add a new record, then do `INSERT` rather than `UPDATE`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `UPDATE` statement is likely not updating anything because there is no record with that `id` value. If you examine the value returned by the FMDB `changes` method (`sqlite3_changes()`), which tells you how many rows were updated, I'd wager it will return zero. When you do an `UPDATE` and the `WHERE` clause fails to find any matches, it does not result in an error, but rather it will quietly succeed while not changing any data. The `changes` method can be used to confirm whether records were really updated.

You can either check first, to see if there is a value with that `id` value, and do an `UPDATE` if found or do an `INSERT` if not. Or, if you know that there will be no value with the same `id` value, you can just do `INSERT` directly.